# Grid/CRUD functionality for django admin interface

Tags: python, django

[image]

In my django 1.7 interface I have a list of objects, as in the screenshot. Although I can click on each and play with them , I'm looking for a way to show all the objects in a spreadsheet within the interface (ideally with CRUD ability). Is there an existing app or simple way to implement this ?

Comment: You can make fields editable right in the admin. Have a look at the [list.editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) property in the admin configuration.

Comment: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html